# Toggle class with JQuery (is-valid, is-invalid)

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there a more elegant way to do this:

```
if (password[0] != password[1]) {
    $('#confirmPassword')[0].setCustomValidity("Passwords do not match")

    $('#confirmPassword').addClass('is-invalid')
    $('#newPassword').addClass('is-invalid')

    $('#confirmPassword').removeClass('is-valid')
    $('#newPassword').removeClass('is-valid')
}
else {
    $('#confirmPassword').removeClass('is-invalid')
    $('#newPassword').removeClass('is-invalid')

    $('#confirmPassword').addClass('is-valid')
    $('#newPassword').addClass('is-valid')
}
```

I feel this code is very boilerplate.

Comment: Why not use the toggle class method:
http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/

Comment: I'm not certain toggle class applies here, if validation is run twice and OP is using toggle class then it will switch to the error state.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`toggleClass()`](https://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/) with second argument which is a boolean to determine whether to add or remove

Can also combine the selectors and chain the methods

```
var isValid = password[0] === password[1];

if (!isValid) {
  $('#confirmPassword')[0].setCustomValidity("Passwords do not match");    
}

$('#confirmPassword, #newPassword')
       .toggleClass('is-invalid', !isValid)
       .toggleClass('is-valid', isValid)
```